# jsonobject cannot be converted to jsonarray android studio

Tags: php, android, json

i want to show images that already i upload to my database SQL using JSON

i already make this code for my android and my server side

getImages.php

```
<?php 

//Importing dbdetails file 
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

//connection to database 
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

//sql query to fetch all images 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";

//getting images 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//response array 
$response = array(); 
$response['error'] = false; 
$response['images'] = array(); 

//traversing through all the rows 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $temp = array(); 
    $temp['id']=$row['id'];
    $temp['name']=$row['name'];
    $temp['url']=$row['url'];
    array_push($response['images'],$temp);
}
//displaying the response 
echo json_encode($response);
```

and then for android code, i make MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Web api url
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/phpcode/getImages.php";

    //Tag values to read from json
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "image";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    //GridView Object
    private GridView gridView;

    //ArrayList for Storing image urls and titles
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        images = new ArrayList<>();
        names = new ArrayList<>();

        //Calling the getData method
        getData();
    }

    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog while our app fetches the data from url
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...","Fetching data...",false,false);

        //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Displaying our grid
                        showGrid(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //Adding our request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }


    private void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray){
        //Looping through all the elements of json array
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            //Creating a json object of the current index
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                //getting json object from current index
                obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //getting image url and title from json object
                images.add(obj.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                names.add(obj.getString(TAG_NAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Creating GridViewAdapter Object
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this,images,names);

        //Adding adapter to gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }

}
```

but the result is error JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONarray?

please help me to fix the code
i need this code in my work, and i'm to confuse to understand the code

===============================
here my gridView class

```
    public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Imageloader to load images
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    //Context
    private Context context;

    //Array List that would contain the urls and the titles for the images
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    public GridViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> images, ArrayList<String> names){
        //Getting all the values
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Creating a linear layout
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //NetworkImageView
        NetworkImageView networkImageView = new NetworkImageView(context);

        //Initializing ImageLoader
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(images.get(position), ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkImageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Setting the image url to load
        networkImageView.setImageUrl(images.get(position),imageLoader);

        //Creating a textview to show the title
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(names.get(position));

        //Scaling the imageview
        networkImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        networkImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));

        //Adding views to the layout
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.addView(networkImageView);

        //Returnint the layout
        return linearLayout;
    }
}
```

================================================
android monitor

> > 10-03 12:20:41.285 24381-24381/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 10-03 12:20:41.285 24381-24381/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86 10-03 12:20:41.461
> >     24381-24388/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active 10-03 12:20:41.461
> >     24381-24388/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation 10-03
> >     12:20:41.543 24381-24381/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown
> >     path: /data/app/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview-1/lib/x86
> >     10-03 12:20:41.560 24381-24381/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run
> >     server: is main process 10-03 12:20:41.935 24381-24410/?
> >     D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
> >     platform default
>
> ```
>                                                       [ 10-03 12:20:41.965 24381:24405 D/         ]
>                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9dfa0b80, tid
> ```
>
> 24405
>
> ```
>                                                       [ 10-03 12:20:41.966 24381:24405 W/         ]
>                                                       Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1
> ```
>
> ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1  10-03 12:20:41.983 24381-24405/? I/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4 10-03 12:20:41.983 24381-24405/?
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 10-03 12:20:41.984 24381-24405/?
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without... 10-03 12:20:41.984
>   24381-24405/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 10-03 12:20:41.993
>   24381-24405/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9dffc920: maj 2 min
>   0 rcv 2 10-03 12:20:42.040 24381-24405/? D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dffc920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9df9f670) 10-03
>   12:20:42.403 24381-24405/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0x9dffc920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9df9f670) 10-03 12:20:42.670
>   24381-24405/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dffc920: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0x9df9f670) 10-03 12:20:42.825
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/art: Before
>   Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView 10-03 12:20:42.864
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   org.json.JSONException: No value for image 10-03 12:20:42.865
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389) 10-03 12:20:42.865
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550) 10-03
>   12:20:42.865 24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview
>   W/System.err:     at
>   net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview.MainActivity.showGrid(MainActivity.java:96)
>   10-03 12:20:42.865
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at
>   net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
>   10-03 12:20:42.865
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at
>   net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:66)
>   10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at
>   net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:58)
>   10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
>   10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>   10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 10-03
>   12:20:42.882 24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 10-03
>   12:20:42.882 24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>   10-03 12:20:42.882
>   24381-24381/net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview W/System.err:
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: In which line are you getting that error?

Comment: the application is installed already to my emulator, but when i open the app, it's said  org.json.JSONException: Value{”error”;false,”images”;[{"id”;"1","name","agakpinggir","url","http",\/\/192.168.42.175\/AndroidImageUpload\/uploads\/1.jpg"}]} of type org.json.JSONObeject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your getData to accept JSONObject. You are passing Jsonobject from your server

```
 private void getData(){
    //Showing a progress dialog while our app fetches the data from url
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...","Fetching data...",false,false);

    //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,DATA_URL,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                    loading.dismiss();
                    try{
                    //Displaying our grid
                    showGrid(response.getJSONArray("images");
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //Adding our request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. This line showGrid(response.getJSONArray("images"));

Comment: use try catch around this line. I will update my code. please check

Comment: The code run well, but when the app is open, there is not images show?

Comment: did you set  android:numColumns="2" in GridView xml

Comment: I set numColums="3", is it ok?

Comment: move Scaling image view below creating linear layout section in adapter. and check below questions. Did the grid view shows the text? Only the image problem? is image link is valid?

Comment: No, no text and images that show, just blank activity when open app

Comment: Could you please debug your code and check everything working. check for  any  exception. and let me know

Comment: please change  public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "image";  to  public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "url";

Comment: give me this error when open app, E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: net.simplifiedcoding.androidcustomgridview, PID: 30306
                                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: E/Volley: [544] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://192.168.42.175/AndroidImageUpload/uploads/1.jpg

Comment: networkImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));  to   networkImageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));  and also there is no image in your given url.. check your urls

Comment: Finally, tahnks

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a JSON array from PHP. Either directly echo `json_encode($temp)` without pushing it into array or use `JSONObjectRequest` instead of `JSONArrayRequest` and parse it accordingly.